# Encoding negative signs from unicode? python

Tags: python, unicode

When I try to encode `Melt_0` from unicode, using:

```
mp = Melt_0.encode('utf-8').strip()
```

`mp` ends up being:

```
￢ﾈﾒ123.37ￂﾠￂﾰC; ￢ﾈﾒ190.07ￂﾠￂﾰF; 149.78ￂﾠK
```

And I can easily fix this by doing:

```
import re
re.sub(r'[^\w.]+', ' ', mp)
```

And I get:

```
 123.37 C 190.07 F 149.78 K
```

The only issue is that the `￢` is supposed to be `-`, and it gets removed when I sub all the non alphanumerics out. How can I keep the `-`s?

Comment: Why are you even encoding in the first place?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams This information comes from html.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of encoding, you need to correct the earlier steps that caused your data to become damaged in the first place:

```
>>> u'￢ﾈﾒ'
u'\uffe2\uff88\uff92'
>>> '\xe2\x88\x92'.decode('utf-8')
u'\u2212'
>>> print u'\u2212'
−
>>> unicodedata.name(u'\u2212')
'MINUS SIGN'

>>> u'ￂﾠￂﾰ'
u'\uffc2\uffa0\uffc2\uffb0'
>>> '\xc2\xa0\xc2\xb0'.decode('utf-8')
u'\xa0\xb0'
>>> print u'\xa0\xb0'
 °
>>> unicodedata.name(u'\xb0')
'DEGREE SIGN'
```

Comment: But how would I use this with my string, which contains those characters but other ones too?

Comment: You would figure out how the data is being damaged in the first place, and then fix that.

Comment: So if `Melt_0` returns `u'\u2212123.37\xa0\xb0C; \u2212190.07\xa0\xb0F; 149.78\xa0K'` then how do I change it so that it returns `'-123.37 °C -190.07 °F 149.78 K'`?

Comment: You can't. But you don't need to; just print it.

Comment: But I do need to because I need the string to be entered in a text field.

Comment: How did you get from "read from a HTML file" to "enter in a text field"?

Comment: I get the text from html so that I can enter it in a text field.

Comment: Okay, so why not copy and paste?

Comment: Long story short it is an automated program that pulls chemical properties from the wikipedia pages of 484 chemicals and enters them in an online database. It was working great until I realized that I had forgotten the minus signs.